# Scala: How to use Functors for multi type parameter trait

Tags: scala, functional-programming, functor, scala-cats

I have and ADT which is basically a wrapper over `Function1`:

```
case class Abstract[M[_], A, B](f:M[A] => M[B]) {
    def fn: M[A] => M[B] = { case x: M[A] => f(x) }
}
```

I want to map over these, so I defined a Functor like so:

```
trait AbstractAPI[E] {
    type AbsO[T] = Abstract[List, E, T]
    // type AbsO[T] = Abstract[List, _, T] => does not work (?)

    implicit val abstractO: Functor[AbsO] = new Functor[AbsO] {
        def map[A, B](fa: AbsO[A])(f: A => B): AbsO[B] = {
            new Abstract(fa.fn andThen { x: List[A] => x.map{ y => f(y) } })
        }
    }
}
```

Now, to actually map over an Abstract, I'd need `AbstractAPI[Int]`, like

```
case object IntAbstractAPI extends AbstractAPI[Int]

object A {
    import IntAbstractAPI._

    val f:List[Int] => List[String] = { case x: List[Int] => x.map{ _.toString.toLowerCase } }
    val hey = (new Abstract(f)).map{ x => x.toInt }
}
```

or

```
object A extends AbstractAPI[Int] {

    val f:List[Int] => List[String] = { case x: List[Int] => x.map{ _.toString.toLowerCase } }

    // FINALLY!
    val res = (new Abstract(f)).map{ x => x.toInt }.map{ _.toFloat + 10f }
    // Abstract[List, Int, Float] = Abstract(<function1>)
}
```

However, in this pattern, I'd have to define case objects for every possible `E`. Here are my questions:

1. Is this the correct way to use Functors?
2. How can I automate the creation of the case objects for every possible `E` (or make the compiler infer it?)

Edit 1:
Further clarification: The above implementation works, but this one does not:

```
object A extends AbstractAPI {

    val f:List[Int] => List[String] = { case x: List[Int] => x.map{ _.toString.toLowerCase } }

    val res = (new Abstract(f)).map{ x => x.toInt }.map{ _.toFloat + 10f }
    // Abstract[List, Int, Float] = Abstract(<function1>)
}
```

gives compilation error:

```
value map is not a member of Abstract[List,Int,String]
```

I assume this is because the compiler is not able to derive a functor for `Abstract[List,Int,String]`?

Comment: This is a bit hard to understand. There's no way the compiler can know how to convert `_` to `T` without being told how, right?

Comment: basically I want to create a wrapper over a function, in such a way that I can map over the wrapper with other functions to create new wrappers of the (composed) functions

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about that, that would mean this is a dead end. Is this still the right way, or am I fundamentally wrong somewhere?

Comment: What you usually do is define the case objects for primitives, and then use shapeless to derive them for any case class / ADT.

Comment: Do you mean "Automatic typeclass instance derivation", like the https://github.com/milessabin/kittens library?

Comment: Isn't this a simple Applicative?

Comment: Or, is this just redefining functors in a somewhat convoluted way?

Comment: Why do you need the resulting type to be monomorphic? This is what seems convoluted, any Functor#map application will result in a concrete value, there no need to go through indirections to achieve that.

Comment: I dont want them to be monomorphic, rather I want to avoid that, the problem is the compiler is not able to infer types (or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *derive* a functor for type parameters that you don't care about.

```
import cats.Functor
import cats.syntax.functor._
```

And I'll rename second type parameter on `Abstract` to `X`, it'll help

```
case class Abstract[M[_], X, A](f: M[X] => M[A]) // forget the fn bit for now
```

You can create typeclass instances not only with a `val`, but also with a `def`. It is allowed to have type parameters and also take other implicit (but only implicit) parameters.

```
type Abs1[X] = ({ type L[A] = Abstract[List, X, A] })

/*implicit*/ def abstract1[X]: Functor[Abs1[X]#L] = new Functor[Abs1[X]#L] {
override def map[A, B](fa: Abstract[List, X, A])(f: A => B): Abstract[List, X, B] =
      Abstract(mx => fa.f(mx).map(f))
}
```

If `map` is all you need from a `List`, you can generalize further for any `M[_]` that has a `Functor` instance. Also placing it into a companion object of `Abstract` enables it to be found without additional imports / inheritance / etc.

```
object Abstract {
  // Abstract.MX[M, X]#L can be replaced with Abstract[M, X, ?] if you use kind-projector
  type MX[M[_], X] = ({ type L[A] = Abstract[M, X, A] })

  implicit def genericFunctor[M[_]: Functor, X] = new Functor[MX[M, X]#L] {
    override def map[A, B](fa: Abstract[M, X, A])(f: A => B): Abstract[M, X, B] =
      Abstract(mx => fa.f(mx).map(f)) // the implementation is the same
  }
}
```

And it works, if you import instances for whatever your `M[_]` is

```
assert {
  import cats.instances.list._ // get Functor[List]

  // map is automatically picked up from Functor[Abstract[List, Int, ?]]
  Abstract(identity[List[Int]])
    .map(Vector.range(0, _))
    .map(_.mkString(""))
    .f(List(1, 2, 3)) == List("0", "01", "012")
}

assert {
  import cats.instances.option._

  Abstract(identity[Option[Int]])
    .map(_ min 42)
    .map(i => Range(i, i + 3))
    .f(Some(11)) == Some(Range(11, 14))
}
```

You can try the code [there](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oleg-py/u0KLs75tScWaiWHvCzY6gg/1)

Answer (score 1):

Answering your second question, you could try this implicit `AbstractAPI[T]` factory:

```
implicit def abstractAPI[T]: AbstractAPI[T] = new AbstractAPI[T] {}
```

Any required implicit evidence for `AbstractAPI[T]` should work, e.g:

```
def f[T : AbstractAPI]: Unit = ()
f
```